# Nginx audio files (wav/ogg/mp3) not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, audio, vps

Audios on prod are not working while working fine on dev environment (Angular 7).

Prod config (VPS):

- Ubuntu 18
- Nginx
- Let's encrypt

**AudioService:**

```
export class AudioService {

    audio = new Audio();

    constructor() { }

    isPlaying() {
        return this.audio.currentTime > 0 && !this.audio.paused && !this.audio.ended && this.audio.readyState > 2;
    }

    play(name: string): void {
        this.audio.src = `assets/audio/${name}`;
        this.audio.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
        this.audio.load();

        if (!this.isPlaying()) {
            this.audio.play();
        }
    }

    pause(): void {
        if (this.isPlaying()) {
            this.audio.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

CORS are enabled on Nodejs side (using Nestjs). **main.ts**:

```
app.enableCors();
```

**Chrome log:**

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no
>   supported source was found.

**Firefox log:**

> NotSupportedError: The media resource indicated by the src attribute
>   or assigned media provider object was not suitable.

Looking at Network console we can see myaudio.wav with:

> Status Code: 206 Partial Content

*Note: Loading images works fine !*

**EDIT:**

Nginx config **/etc/nginx/sites-available/mywebsite**:

```
# Redirection
server {
   # if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
   #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   # } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

# Config
server {
     server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

     root /home/foo/mywebsite/gui;

     index index.html index.htm;

     location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
       proxy_pass    http://my.ip:3000/;

       # Websocket
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    if ($host = 'www.mywebsite.com') {
       return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

On dev environment localhost:4200/assets/audio/myaudio.wav → works fine

On prod environment https://mywebsite.com/assets/audio/myaudio.wav → returns home page

While https://mywebsite.com/assets/image.jpg → works fine

Only audios don't work.

Comment: Sounds like missing audio codec on your prod server.

Comment: @TGrif still not working after installing ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Comment: @TGrif I think this is a Nginx issue. Updated my question.

Comment: Can you comment all `redirects` you have in your `nginx` config

Comment: @midrizi already tried `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assets/audio/clock.wav'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assets/audio/clock.wav'` (despite the file exists)

Comment: Can you comment `root` and try again?

Comment: That's what I did.

Comment: @Emerica can you confirm that the audio file is included in the assets after the build?

Comment: @GuerricP Sure yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`max_ranges`](http://nginx.org/r/max_ranges) to 0.

For your case, this would look like something like this:

```
location ~ \.wav$ {
    max_ranges 0;
}
```

Meaning the rule applies to every `wav` file regardless of their location.

Comment: It works ! I've waste so many hours on this and it was such an easy solution. I can't believe I didn't find anything...

Comment: Hopefully SO helps!